# Formatting data for use with JSON and D3.js

Tags: mysql, json, d3.js

I have the following data in my MySQL database. These three columns are a subset of a table that I have selected using a query.

```
Value         Date               Time

230.8         13/08/08           15:01:22+22
233.7         13/08/08           15:13:12+22
234.5         13/08/08           15:40:33+22
```

I want to represent this data on a graph of (Value) versus (Date & Time) in a chronological manner. What is the format I need to put the above data into before using JSON cause I've had a look at a few tutorials and when I apply the same logic (like this:http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) I don't seem to be getting any graph at all.

Or will JSON and D3.js not work for my requirement? Do I need to look at something else? Like some other JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vague, but I'll try to adress a few of your topics to help you get started.

- Firstly, I would suggest finding the visualization that fits your needs. From the data subset that you showed in the question, I would suggest maybe [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062085). It is interesting because if you have multiple *values* for different *times* in a given *day*, you could construct various time series graphs and compare them interactively. There are other options, so you should explore and find a good starting point to improve and adapt to your needs.
- Regarding the origin/format of the data, if you are able to extract that data you showed to a variable (with PHP, for example), you can then manipulate the data and build a structure from it. It doesn't necessarily have to be JSON and/or CSV. As long as you can handle it with d3.js's API functions. It isn't *very* difficult, but it is something that requires you to understand and read about the topic. First understand how to query for your needs with MySQL. Then, I would suggest starting [here](http://www.json.org/) if you decide to go with JSON.
- The example visualization I mentioned above uses a [CSV](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4062085/population.csv) file as a data source. Other option could be for instance to build a CSV file (or data structure - ie, an array) to feed into d3.js. There are various questions covering "how to create CSV with PHP", so you shouldn't have much difficulty finding the info you need.

Either way, after you feel confortable with what you know about these topics, start breaking your problem into smaller tasks and finding answers to one question at a time. If you need, post more questions here in SO and include your attempts at coding a solution, this will definitely get you all the help you might need.

Answer (score 0):

in python it would look like this:

```
import json
output = json.dumps(['data', {'data_1': ('230.8', '13/08/08', '15:01:22+22')}, {'data_2': ('233.7', '13/08/08', '15:13:12+22')}, {'data_3': ('234.5', '13/08/08', '15:40:33+22')}])
print output
```

more information about python and json can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)